# How to create this special counter on a specific value in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, counter

I've problem that I've been struggling with for hours.
I'm trying to create a special counter on a column from a temporary table, my table has many columns, one of them is col1:

```
col1 |
######
X    | 
X    | 
A    | 
B    | 
X    | 
C    | 
X    | 
D    |
```

The special counter should be like this:

```
col1 | counter
###############
X    | 1
X    | 2
A    | 2
B    | 2
X    | 3
C    | 3
X    | 4
D    | 4
```

**it should count the "X" value only, and keep it unchanged in case the value was anything else.**

I tried a lot of things, the closest I got was by creating another temp table with counter only, and then join it with the original one,  but the result was like this:

```
col1 | counter
###############
X    | 1
X    | 2
A    | NULL
B    | NULL
X    | 3
C    | NULL
X    | 4
D    | NULL
```

**So, how can I create this special counter?**

Comment: What column are you ordering by?  And what version of SQL Server?

Comment: @DanField, there's another SortOrder column in the temporary table, I'm using it to order values, but it's not shown in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Row_Number()` within a `CASE` should do the trick.

You'll notice I added a field ID to maintain a sequence.

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,col1 varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'X'),
(2,'X'),
(3,'A'),
(4,'B'),
(5,'X'),
(6,'C'),
(7,'X'),
(8,'D')

Select ID,Col1
      ,Counter = max(counter) over (Order By ID)
 From (
       Select ID
             ,col1
             ,counter = case when col1='X' then row_number() over (Partition By col1 Order by ID) else null end
        From  @YourTable
      ) A
 Order By ID
```

Returns

```
ID  Col1    Counter
1   X       1
2   X       2
3   A       2
4   B       2
5   X       3
6   C       3
7   X       4
8   D       4
```

Comment: Actually I mentioned in my question that I don't want NULL values, please see the last result table, the counter should stay unchanged in this case.

Comment: @AbeerSul Misread the question.  I'll take another poke at it

Comment: @AbeerSul is there another column which contains the sequence?

Comment: could you clarify how this works? I don't understand it

Comment: @AbeerSul The counter in the sub-query will generate a row_number() for just X.  Then the max(counter)  is yet another window function.  It will grab the max X-Counter from the current and preceding rows.  The window functions are your friends.  Well worth your time to get comfortable with them,

Answer (score 4):

Here it is in an update statement. The statement increments the variable every time an X is encountered and updates every row with the correct value.

```
declare @counter int = 0;
update   #temp
set      counter = @counter
       , @counter += case when col1 = 'X' then 1
                          else 0
                     end;
```

Comment: I did not know you could update a scalar and a column in the set portion of an update.  Cool.

Comment: Only thing I'd add is that this might not get sequenced using the ordering column the way the OP wants....

Answer (score 2):

There is much simpler and streightforward solution. We just need a little observation: the counter equals to count of `X`s in previous rows:

```
select id, 
       col1,
       (select count(*) from @t where id <= t.id and col1 = 'X') as counter
from @t t
```